# Should each heading tag include text related to the page title for dynamic content?

Tags: seo, content, tags, heading

New pages are created within my website by users who add new content. Currently the heading tags are the same for each new page. For SEO purposes, would it be better to relate the heading tags to the page title or keep them the same static throughout the website?

I have done some research and it seems that heading tags that related to a specific page's content (and not the overall website niche) seem to perform better, or is this just coincidence?

Comment: Can you include example(s)? What is your current heading for those pages?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the h-tags to your advantage for SEO - I so often see them overlooked - and to do that you need to use them to provide relevant, succinct descriptions of the page's content.

The `<h1>` tag generally should contain the main theme of the page, which could be the page title or a variation/elaboration of it. If your exisitng, static `<h1>` tag is relevant to the content of every page and the users can create `<h2>` sub-headings then that could be enough for SEO. The chances of that being true for every page is unlikely, however, and changing up the `<h1>` tags depending on what's actually on the page is your best bet.